# Prolog DCG: Match different symbols on a chain

Tags: recursion, prolog, dcg, left-recursion, failure-slice

I'm trying to match some sentences (e.g. 001 [0,0,1], (1+(1/0)) ['(',1,+,'(',1,/,0,')',')'], and so on.

I've made myself following small DCG.

```
g3 --> s3.
s3 --> e3.

e3 --> eAdd.
e3 --> eMin.
e3 --> eMul.
e3 --> eDiv.
e3 --> n3.

eAdd --> ['('],e3,['+'],e3,[')'].
eMin --> ['('],e3,['-'],e3,[')'].
eMul --> ['('],e3,['*'],e3,[')'].
eDiv --> ['('],e3,['/'],e3,[')'].


n3 --> d3.
n3 --> n3,d3.
d3 --> [0].
d3 --> [1].
```

Now my problem is, it won't match with sentences using -,* or / but it works for recursive sentences using only +.

E.g:

```
phrase(g3,['(',1,'+','(',1,'+',1,')',')']).
```

Will work, but

```
phrase(g3,['(',1,'+','(',1,'/',1,')',')']).
```

Won't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is due to the rule

```
n3 --> n3,d3.
```

This is a so-called *left recursive* rule. It says that to match an `n3`, you must first match an `n3`, for which you must first match an `n3`, for which you must first, etc., and this never terminates.

Basically, you want every recursive grammar rule to first match some nonterminals before performing a recursive call. (Similarly, in the bodies of "normal" Prolog predicates, you should have other goals before any recursive call.)

If you change this rule to the right-recursive variant

```
n3 --> d3,n3.
```

your grammar becomes well-behaved:

```
?- phrase(g3,['(',1,'+','(',1,'+',1,')',')']).
true ;
false.

?- phrase(g3,['(',1,'+','(',1,'/',1,')',')']).
true ;
false.

?- length(L, 6), phrase(g3, L).
L = ['(', 0, +, 0, 0, ')'] ;
L = ['(', 0, +, 0, 1, ')'] ;
L = ['(', 0, +, 1, 0, ')'] ;
L = ['(', 0, +, 1, 1, ')'] ;
L = ['(', 1, +, 0, 0, ')'] ;
L = ['(', 1, +, 0, 1, ')'] ;
L = ['(', 1, +, 1, 0, ')'] ;
L = ['(', 1, +, 1, 1, ')'] ;
```

etc.

Here are a few old questions about left recursion in DCGs that might provide additional helpful information:

[DCG and left recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503953/dcg-and-left-recursion)

[Removing left recursion in DCG - Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663652/removing-left-recursion-in-dcg-prolog)

[Removing left recursion grammar using DCG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503334/removing-left-recursion-grammar-using-dcg)

Answer (score 5):

First of all, whenever you are using DCGs, consider to

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

This permits to use a much more readable syntax.  Here are the rules
and queries that change due to this convention.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

eAdd --> "(", e3, "+", e3, ")".
eMin --> "(", e3, "-", e3, ")".
eMul --> "(", e3, "*", e3, ")".
eDiv --> "(", e3, "/", e3, ")".

d3 --> "0".
d3 --> "1".

?- phrase(g3,"(1+(1+1))").

?- phrase(g3,"(1+(1/1))").
```

Note that already your first query has a problem, even if it succeeds.
This can be easily seen on the toplevel:

```
?- phrase(g3,"(1+(1+1))").
   true
;  resource_error(_). % ERROR: Out of local stack
```

So the toplevel insisted that there is something else apart from the
actual success.  To narrow this down in a systematic manner I will use
a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) which adds **`false`** to regular goals and
**`{false}`** within the grammar.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

g3 --> s3, {false}.

s3 --> e3, {false}.

e3 --> {false}, eAdd.
e3 --> {false}, eMin.
e3 --> {false}, eMul.
e3 --> {false}, eDiv.
e3 --> n3, {false}.

n3 --> {false}, d3.
n3 --> n3, {false}, d3.

?- phrase(g3,"(1+(1+1))"), false.
```

*Because* this tiny fragment loops, the entire program loops, too.  Note
that `+` is no longer part of the program!  The problem had nothing to
do with `+` at all.